# Can't set empty object as default value for param with type Record

Tags: typescript

```
type SimpleObject = Record<string, any>
<T extends SimpleObject>(param: T = {}) => param
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.   '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, any>'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript does not know the shape of `T`, it may or maynot match `{}`, so you need to explicitly tell that you know `{}` is `T` as mentioned below:

[TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/KWzj2W)

```ts
type SimpleObject = Record<string, any>
<T extends SimpleObject>(param: T = {} as T) => param
```